# Autogrow the height of @Html.TextAreaFor depending on the amount of text

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to auto grow the height of `@Html.TextAreaFor` depending on the amount of text do display?

Here is what I have tried but the height does not adjust:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, 5, 30, 
                  htmlAttributes: new { style = "min-width:500px; max-width:100%;min-height:50px;max-height:100%;width:100%;border-style: none " })
```

Thanks,
SEB

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to autosize your textarea, like this:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
function autosize(){
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  },0);
}
```

This sample came from this link https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/czgrf

If you just want to display content you can use document ready, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    textarea.style.cssText = 'height:' + textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
});
```

Comment: This seems to only work when typing text. I am trying to display text.

Comment: You can adapt the code and use jquery's document ready function. I edited the answer